# Add/attach saved pdf to node with rules

Tags: views, rules, files

I have a setup with [views PDF](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_pdf) which send email after creating a node. (This works)

For logging purpose I would like the PDF added to my node in a filefield.
Is there a rule action/php code  available to add the saved PDF to the filefield.

Answer (score 1):

For adding/attaching a file to a node using code you need a file object. If you know the **path of the created PDF file**, just try the following code in the **hook** you need. I used this code in **hook_node_insert** for attaching a programmatically created PDF file, while creating that node.

```
$source_node = node_load($nid); //load your required node here.
$file_path = 'your file path';
$file = new stdClass;
$file->uid = $source_node->uid;
$file->filename = $filename; //your file name;
$file->uri = $file_path;
$file->filemime = file_get_mimetype($file_path);
// Make it permanent, otherwise it will get deleted later.
$file->status = FILE_STATUS_PERMANENT;
// Save file object to make it a 'managed file'.
$file_obj = file_copy($file, 'new path for your file', FILE_EXISTS_REPLACE);


$source_node->your_file_field_name['und'][0] = array(
 'fid'  => $file_obj->fid,
 'uid'  => $file_obj->uid,
 'filename'  => $file_obj->filename,
 'uri'  => $file_obj->uri,
 'filemime'  => $file_obj->filemime,
 'filesize'  => $file_obj->filesize,
 'status'  => 1,
 'display'  => 1,
 'description'  => '', 
 );

node_save($source_node);
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: copy the file works. but i still get error:
EntityMalformedException: Missing bundle property on entity of type node. in entity_extract_ids() (rule 7879 van /includes/common.inc). @Abin

Comment: i used code in php filed in rules.

Answer (score 0):

```
$nid = $node->nid;
$source_node = node_load($nid);
$filename = 'filename.pdf'; //your specific filename 
$dir = 'public://'.$filename; //path to specific file with name
$file_size = filesize($dir);
$source_node->type = 'my_nodetype'; // error if not used

//New file object
$file = new stdClass;
$file->uid = $source_node->uid;
$file->filename = $filename; //your file name;
$file->uri = $dir;
$file->filemime = file_get_mimetype($dir);
// Make it permanent, otherwise it will get deleted later.
$file->status = FILE_STATUS_PERMANENT;
// Save file object to make it a 'managed file'.
$file_obj = file_copy($file, 'public://', FILE_EXISTS_REPLACE);
$file->type = 'document';

$source_node->field_custom_name['und'][0] = array(
 'fid'  => $file_obj->fid,
 'uid'  => $file_obj->uid,
 'filename'  => $file_obj->filename,
 'uri'  => $file_obj->uri,
 'filemime'  => $file_obj->filemime,
 'filesize'  => $file_obj->filesize,
 'status'  => 1,
 'display'  => 1,
 'description'  => '', 
 );

node_save($source_node);
file_usage_add($file_obj, 'file', 'node', $source_node->nid);
```

PDF is attached to current node. thanks for help.
Is anypone has the code to do the same with entitywrapper. please share.